Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322) const headerKey: never
I would like to ask why this particular line:
rowData[headerKey] = value;

is giving me this error:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
const headerKey: never
Here is the code:
const exportData = (
    table.getSortedRowModel().rows.length > 0
      ? table.getSortedRowModel().rows // Use sorted data if available
      : table.getCoreRowModel().rows
  ).map((row) => {
    const rowData: Partial<TableDataGeneralTemp> = {};
    row.getVisibleCells().forEach((cell) => {
      if (cell.column.columnDef.header !== "IsSelected") {
        const value = cell.getValue() as string;
        const headerKey = cell.column.columnDef.header as keyof TableDataGeneralTemp; 

        rowData[headerKey] = value;
      }
    });
    return rowData;
  });

Here are the interfaces:
interface TableData1 {
  application_date: string; // ISO 8601 date string
  application_id: string;
  applicant_name: string;
  institution?: string;
  applicant_email?: string;
  status: string;
  payment_status: string;
}

interface TableData2 {
  document_Request_Workflow_No: string;
  document_Request_Name: string;
  status: string;
  created: string;
  last_Updated: string;
}

interface TableData3 {
  invoice_no: string;
  gross_revenue: string;
  payment_status: string;
  payment_method: string;
  platform_fee: string;
  net_revenue: string;
}

interface DocStatusData {
  document_request_status_no: string;
  application_id: string;
  document_name: string;
  type_of_copy: string;
  status: string;
}

interface InvoiceData {
  invoice_date: string;
  invoice_no: string;
  payment_date: string;
  amount: string;
  status: string;
}

interface ReceiptData {
  receipt_date: string;
  transaction_no: string;
  payment_date: string;
  status: string;
}

// interface TableData4 {
//   audit_log_no: string;
//   timestamp: string;
//   user: string;
//   activity: string;
//   status: string;
// }

interface CommonTableData {
  // uniqueColumn: string;
  isSelected: boolean;
}

type TableDataGeneralTemp =
  | TableData1
  | TableData2
  | TableData3
  | DocStatusData
  | InvoiceData
  | ReceiptData;
type TableDataGeneral = (
  | TableData1
  | TableData2
  | TableData3
  | DocStatusData
  | InvoiceData
  | ReceiptData
) &
  CommonTableData;

I have tried adding this safety check:
if (headerKey && headerKey in rowData) {
    rowData[headerKey as keyof TableDataGeneralTemp] = value;
}

However, it did not work. The function used to not generate any type errors until someone added their codes to the component, and now I cannot figure out how to get rid of the type error.

Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now when I look at it I get errors that table and TableDataGeneralTemp are not defined, and that leads to lots of errors you're not asking about.  Please make sure your example shows what you want it to show when you look at it in a standalone IDE. Currently it risks being closed as lacking debugging details.

Instead of:
if (headerKey && headerKey in rowData) {
    rowData[headerKey as keyof TableDataGeneralTemp] = value;
}

Try:
(rowData as any)[headerKey] = value;

